# In crystal report sometimes data is coming for different parameters than selected

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server.
The occurrence of such a problem is not very often but sometimes data comes is not exactly what the query is. Like if I select

```
    Subject = 'Maths' and Group = 'A' report coming is either comes for 
    Subject = 'Chemistry' and Group = 'A' or Subject = Maths and Group = C 
    or 
    Subject = 'English' and Group = 'B'
```

You can make any combination. The query executes correctly the only problem is that it doesn't come for submitted parameters.
It happens very few times but when it happens no replies are possible.
Please help to find the reason behind this mixing of parameters.
My guess is that somehow SQL server is mixing with different users requests if requests submitted almost on same time. if one user requests Maths for A group and another Maths for B group both get the same result either with Maths with A or Maths with B like that.

Comment: where is parameter in your code?

Comment: with the sql query like select * from traineerecord where gr = a. this sent to crystal and report is called with this selected data.